# Cannot convert from derived class pointer to base class pointer

Tags: c++, gcc

I have a simple 3-class hierarchy.

```
class A { ... }
class B : public A { ... }
class C : public B { ... }
```

And I am trying to do something like this (where GetCPointer returns a C*):

```
A* baseClassPointer = GetCPointer();
```

But I am getting this error.

```
cannot convert 'C*' to 'A*' in initialization
```

I was under the assumption that this kind of conversion would be implicit. I have also tried `static_cast` and `dynamic_cast` which did not solve this error. What am I missing?

Comment: It should work the way you expected… can you post a minimal example that reproduces the problem?

Comment: It works for me: https://onlinegdb.com/H5XpNtLYc

Comment: Perhaps the headers you included only have a forward declaration for one or more of the classes, and this the compiler doesn’t know that C is a sub-subclass of A?  If so, then the fix would be to make sure you #include the files that contain the full definitions of A, B, and C before doing the implicit cast.

Comment: Yes this was it, just needed to include B's header. Thanks!